# win32com.printout prints only one page with loop in python

Tags: python, win32com

I'm trying to code a script where an excel file is updated through a list in python and then printing the result in a page.

After multiple trials and errors, I got this code, but it prints only one page, despite being in a loop.

```
for i in range(len(employee_list)):
  building_cell = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2)
  building_cell.value = employee_list[i][1]

  name_cell = worksheet.cell(row=6, column=3)
  name_cell.value = employee_list[i][4]

  department_cell = worksheet.cell(row=7, column=3)
  department_cell.value = employee_list[i][2]

  job_cell = worksheet.cell(row=8, column=3)
  job_cell.value = employee_list[i][3]

  workbook.save(r'employee_list.xlsx')
  workbook.close()

  o = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
  o.visible = False
  wb = o.Workbooks.Open(r'employee_list.xlsx')
  ws = wb.Worksheets("Template")
  ws.printout()
  wb.Close(False)
  del(wb)
```

I'm newish at python, but shouldn't it excecute everything until it finishes the loop? I don't have this problem with my other `for` loops.

Comment: Looks like you're opening and closing the same workbook during every iteration of your loop.  I suspect you're experiencing a timing issue in that before the print can even begin you've replaced the workbook with a newer version.  Is the single printout you're getting for the last entry in the list?  It's really hard to tell what is going on with just this snippet of code.

Comment: It prints only the first entry in the list.

Comment: Looks like you must be opening the workbook and selecting the worksheet outside of your loop, but you close the workbook inside the loop (workbook.close) after the first iteration so I suspect all other iterations of the loop are failing.

Comment: I opened the workbook inside the loop but it still only prints the first line and doesn't close the workbook after the loop finishes. Yesterday, I tried outside the loop and it closed it fine.